# What happens when recaptchaV3 monthly quota is reached?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

According to google documentation:

**If a v3 site key exceeds its monthly quota, then site_verify may fail open by returning a static score 0.9 and an error message `"Over free quota."` for the remainder of the month. There are no user-visible indications when v3 sites are over quota.**

They don't really specify what the response will be like, will the success indicator still be true? Meaning that the token was successfully validated? Will they still send the action in the response?

I'm not concerned about the static 0.9 score, but rather that the success indicator being false or the action being empty would cause issues for me.

Has anyone had to deal with reaching recaptchasV3 limit before?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.